# How to hide every other row in a table?

Tags: javascript, html, tampermonkey

I have a typical html table, with tr and td's inside them. How can I use Javascript (Tampermonkey) to hide every other `tr`?

The tr's don't have specific classes. They only have the `tr` attribute.

Comment: Do you want to do it with CSS?

Comment: Please try to search before asking questions. This is not hard to research

Comment: *They only have the tr attribute* Do you mean the `tr` tag?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give this a shot:

```
var rows = document.querySelectorAll('tr:nth-child(odd)'); /* or even */
for(var r = 0; r < rows.length; r++){
    rows[r].style.display = 'none';
}
```

Basically find all the odd (or even) rows and set their `display` attribute to `none`.

Tampermonkey just injects vanilla JavaScript. Nothing special about it.

Comment: Is there some reason to use JS here instead of CSS?

Comment: The question was specific to using the browser plugin Tampermonkey. Otherwise, CSS is the way to go to accomplish this.

Comment: @J.Titus, This works perfectly! Just a picky thing, how can I make it start from the second even `tr`?   (i.e., It shows the first two and then starts hiding).

Comment: @corybantic Just change the `for` loop slightly to start at the second record: `for(var r = 1; r <= rows.length; r++)`

Answer (score 4):

You can easily hide table rows with CSS.

For odd rows:

```
tr:nth-child(odd) {display: none;}
```

For even rows:

```
tr:nth-child(even) {display: none;}
```

Answer (score -1):

This may help:

[jQuery table styling vs CSS table styling for alternate rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3359181/jquery-table-styling-vs-css-table-styling-for-alternate-rows)

Comment: why the downvote, downvoters? the answer in the article is the same as the answer below with upvotes!